# How do I make English (United States) the default language in Firefox?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, language-support

When I am typing in a text box within Firefox, the spell checker uses English (United Kingdom) by default. I would like to change this to English (United States). Here is what I have tried already:

- Within a text box I have right-clicked and selected "English (United States)". This works but only on a per-session basis. I want English (United States) to be the default when I run Firefox.
- I have gone to about:config within Firefox to check the value of "spellchecker.dictionary". The value is "en_US".
- I have gone to Settings > Language Support and put "English (United States)" at the top.
- I have read the file /etc/default/locale; all the values begin "en_US".

I am using Firefox Version 16.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I figured out. Firefox on Ubuntu uses a different spellchecker than other platforms. In /usr/lib/firefox there is a symlink called dictionaries which maps to /usr/share/hunspell. I deleted all the files there except for en_US.aff and en_US.dic and now I am getting US English by default. I can't figure out what package the other English versions are a part of. On searching in Synaptic there is a hunspell-en-us and hunspell-en-ca but no other English version in the repos. I'm assuming the other English versions will return when whatever package it is gets updated.

Comment: can you post the result of `locale`